# Excel formula which calculates non-missing values from rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have an excel spreadsheet and my company is building an app that will use data from this spreadsheet. I need to send over some trial data but the excel is about 5000 rows long.

My managers said to pick values from the columns that have the most values entered (least blank or "empty" cells). Obviously, that is very tedious to check by hand given my file.

What would be a formula I can use to identify how many non blank cells there are by row, then I could do a descending sort to pick the entries I want for my trial?

Comment: What does `non-missing` mean? is it non `0` or non empty string `""` or not true blank?

Comment: Sorry by non-missing I simply meant blanks. I am looking for rows with values in the cells, mostly strings, but could timestamps, numerical values etc.

Comment: @BigBen I'm sorry I'm really bad at making a table on Stack...

Comment: `COUNTA` or `COUNTBLANK` but if you have empty strings `""` then you'll have issues.

Comment: @BigBen COUNTA worked like a charm. Thanks so much !! You have an awesome day

Answer (score 1):

For the first row, something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(1:1<>""))
```

This will not count empties or cells containing formulas returning blank.